# Зависит ли отображение сайтов от того какая у пользователя Операционная Система?

Tags: тестирование

Зависит ли отображение сайтов от того какая у пользователя Операционная Система? Если да, то как?

Comment: Да, как минимум от шрифтов

Comment: Ну например ОС диктует то, какие браузеры на ней вообще могут работать (привет Андроид, iOS, Болген-ОС итп). А по браузерам смотрим какие фичи они не поддерживают (например, https://caniuse.com/css-text-box-trim)

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Отображение сайта зависит от браузера, его движка и версии, а также от параметров монитора. Но если сайт содержит ,например, Flash-контент, то он может не работать на современной ОС/браузере. Это не связано с самой ОС, а только с наличием и версией Flash-плеера на компьютере.

Comment: Если движок браузера как-то связан с ОС (а он связан, например, через рендеринг шрифтов), то отображение начинает зависеть от ОС. Да и canvas-фингерпринтинг тоже работает всё-таки

Answer (score 0):

Как выглядит современный сайт внутри окна браузера, полностью зависит от самого браузера (по крайней мере, это верно для сайтов, фронтенд-часть которых сделана только с помощью стандартных веб-технологий). Но это не значит что отображение сайта вообще никогда не зависит от ОС. Браузер может полагаться на стандартный стиль ОС для некоторых элементов: ползунков, кнопок (не изменённых с помощью CSS-стилей) и т.д. Тогда сайт иногда может выглядеть немного по-разному в одной и той же версии браузера, но в разных ОС. Насколько я знаю, Chrome использует единый кроссплатформенный стиль для всех стандартных элементов. Как с этим обстоят дела в других популярных браузерах - не знаю; вёрстка и фронтенд - не моя специальность. В экзотических браузерах может быть всё что угодно.

---

Нужно учитывать, что отличия из-за ОС затрагивают лишь небольшое число элементов страницы. Как правило, отличия есть лишь между стандартными версиями элементов,а через CSS внешний вид элементов в разных ОС меняется одинаково. Т.е. вероятность встретить заметное отличие из-за ОС очень мала. Но если устранение этих отличий очень важно, то есть всякие онлайн-сервисы, позволяющие проверить как сайт выглядит на разных комбинациях ОС+браузер. Наконец, можно самому использовать браузеры внутри виртуальных машин с разными ОС, а потом сравнивать скрины.